# When validating cox model: NaN when using rms::validate, Divergence or singularity in [all] samples

Tags: r, prediction, cox-regression

I would like to fit a Cox model for prediction of 1-year survival using a specific set of predictors. The data contains 78 events in 620 subjects.

I don't think my problem is related to my data, so here is an example using R data in which I am also unable to use rms::validate().

```
library(survival)
library(rms)

data(cancer, package="survival")
dd <- datadist(cancer) 
options(datadist= 'dd')

# fit
s1yr <- Surv(cancer$time, cancer$status)
cph.euro.log <- cph(s1yr ~ log(age), data = cancer, method = 'exact',
                   x = TRUE, y = TRUE, surv = TRUE)

# validate
validate(cph.euro.log, B=20)
```

Divergence or singularity in 20 samples

|  | index.orig | training | test | optimism | index.corrected | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dxy | 0.1005 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0 |
| R2 | 0.0179 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0 |
| Slope | 1.0000 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0 |

The output from validate above is similar to what I get for my real data. The function gives point estimates for the predictive performance measures but nothing more (just NaN). What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the author's mouth: The function is not yet available for survival models fit using the 'exact' method. If one drops 'exact' and uses, for example, the default method 'efron', it works.